# What caused apache to crash?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, server-crashes, apc

I have a high load server using php/apache/APC working fine for months. In the last 2 days it has crashed midday. if I restart apache it works so the problem is probably in the apache/php/apc stack. 
It runs at up to 200 hits/sec running highly optimized PHP script with some algorithms. I use newrelic for monitoring and as far as I can see the problem is not related to databases or disk access.

Here is what I see in newrelic 
[image]

[image]

I don't see anything special in syslog or error log of apache.

Does the high spike in running instances count tells something?

What can I check to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: The RAM spike is suspect...maybe a memory leak? It's very difficult to tell. The spike in apache instances tells me that something triggered the rapid spawning of apache workers which then eventually crashed. You'd likely have to see it happen and pull the logs as it becomes unstable.

Comment: I believe that a memory leak will increase memory consumption gradually. the immediate spike suggests it maybe something else.